# Website written using ReactJs is not working on Iphones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I developed a website which was build using ReactJs library. I tried deploying on Heroku when there was no logic only markup and css and everything was fine. But when all logic was completed website stopped working on Iphones for some reason(all the modern browsers). All I am getting is white, blank page. And there is no errors in Sentry. On the other hand site perfectly works on Android devices. Any help would help

Solved Issue: problem was caused by regular expressions

Comment: Provide link to the website atleast.

Comment: https://new.dengiclick.kz/

Comment: i forgot to mention that what does not work is /personal-room route (first icon in the right top corner)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4AbMk87 This seems to be the problem.